# Is it possible to programmatically add a web part to a page in a sharepoint hosted app (JS)

Tags: 2013, web-part, project-server

I've been looking for a way to add a web part to a page using JSOM/CSOM or any other api available to sharepoint hosted apps.

The only solutions I have found so far are for custom sharepoint solutions. Could anyone confirm that this is (im)possible?

To be clear, I want to add a web part to a sharepoint page. Not to a page of my app.

Comment: If you give access to the library that holds the web part page, then you could probably edit it through jsom, and then add web part. Heh, if you could do that you could actually edit the iframe tag that holds your app, and through html5 (sandbox allow attribute) give full access, which renders the DNS-solution for cross origin lockdown useless.. so perhaps not

Comment: is this what you are looking for : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79579/add-an-existing-webpart-using-the-sharepoint-client-object-model ?

Comment: @CameronVerhelst that answer is csom, not jsom. And, for what it is worth, missing the auth, but could probably be converted to jsom. This might be interesting though: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/86569/627

Comment: I realise this, but the question does ask for either JSOM/CSOM

Comment: @CameronVerhelst SharePoint hosted app?

Comment: I've got nearly 0 experience with the whole "APP" model in SP 2013, but this article seems to reinforce my thinking that CSOM is an option in Hosted SP 2013 apps: http://www.tuyrcorp.com/sharepoint-app-code-calls-into-sharepoint-2013-using-csom-and-rest-calls/

Comment: If anyone is interested, I have found something interesting myself in the meantime at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185010(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @CameronVerhelst, the article discussion CSOM above is actually refering to what eirikb referes to as JSOM. The terminology here is not really crystal clear :)

Comment: I think indeed something is not entirely clear to me :). I will have to look into it one day, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### How to add WebPart client object on page via JSOM

```
function addWebPart(webUrl, pageUrl,webPartXml,zoneId,zoneIndex, Success,Error){
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(webUrl);
    var web = context.get_web();

    var file = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(webUrl + pageUrl);
    var webPartMngr = file.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    var webPartDef = webPartMngr.importWebPart(webPartXml);
    var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
    webPartMngr.addWebPart(webPart, zoneId, zoneIndex);

    context.load(webPart);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
        Success(webPart);
      },
      Error
    );
}
```

Example: add Content Editor on root web

```
var webPartXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">' +
    '<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>' + 
    '<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>' + 
    '<Title>$Resources:core,ContentEditorWebPartTitle;</Title>' +
    '<Description>$Resources:core,ContentEditorWebPartDescription;</Description>' +
    '<PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>' +
'</WebPart>';

addWebPart('/','Pages/default.aspx',webPartXml,'Left',1,function(webPart){
    console.log(webPart.get_title() + ' has been added'); 
},function(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Perhaps send in `context` and `web`, since you would need to call `set_webRequestExecutorFactory`? Also, I tried to do this with REST earlier before your post, but I wasn't able to call `addWebPart`, I just got _404_, any idea why? (`importWebPart` worked fine, at least I got some kind of reply)

Comment: Thanks! Good idea, but I have not found a way to add web part on page via REST yet.

Comment: "I wasn't able to call addWebPart, I just got 404, any idea why?" The AddWebPart_Client method of the SPLimitedWebPartManager class is the client-side equivalent of the AddWebPart method. Unfortunately, this method is decorated with a ClientCallableMethod attribute having ClientLibraryTargets=ClientLibraryTargets.NonRESTful, making this method unusable from REST calls.